# Missing Zip Codes in Google APi

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have enables Google Autocomplete on our Website but we have found some zip codes do not register with the API. 60514 will populate Clarendon Hills, IL 60514, but the follow zip codes do not work.
32312 – Tallahassee, FL
48260 – Detroit, MI
10510 – Westchester County, NY
29302 – Spartanburg, SC
24001 – Roanoke, VA

All these zip codes are active and verified from Zip-codes.com. You can even find the zip code in Google Maps but not in the Google API Autocomplete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is something you should take up with Google support.

Comment: report it here: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en

Comment: Hey Mat. The Zip codes I provided show up in Google Maps but there is an issue with the autocomplete. Check out the Autocomplete when you sign up for an account with stack Over Flow. if you type in 29302 it will not autocomplete to Spartanburg, SC

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you may have to pass the country code ("US") following the zip code to the `GeocodingApi.geocode` function as the argument for the address to be resolved. Most US zip codes are resolved without that, but some would yield empty results unless followed by "US". For example:

```
`14264` yields no results
`14264, US` yields "Buffalo, NY, 14264, US"
```